# arboricity of a graph and forest decomposition

Tags: graph-theory

definitions: For a graph G=(V,E)
, |V|=v,|E|=e
, we will define its density to be d(G):=e/v
and m(G)=
max
d(H),H⊆G
. We will say that G is dense if m(G)=d(G)
, and we will say that G is densest if for any H⊊G
d(H)<d(G)
,

we will also define d1(G)=e/(v−1)
, and m1(G)=max
d1(H)
and say that G
is k1
densest if for any H⊆G
such that H
has more than one vertices: d1(H)<d1(G)
.

ρ(G) denotes the arboricity of G (minimum number of forests required to cover all edges).

question:
prove the following: Let G be connected with ρ(G) > 1 and for every e ∈ E ρ(G-e)<ρ(G). Then for every e ∈ E
any (ρ(G) − 1)-forest decomposition of G − e is a decomposition into ρ(G) − 1
spanning trees of G.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, please use MathJax to format your posts.

Comment: Also I believe this is a lemma proved in a standard proof of the theorem of Nash-Williams. I'm sure you can find it online.

Comment: @mathmath: This is proved as lemma 1 in https://tcs.uj.edu.pl/documents/35126571/149598393/2022.05.12+-+Jacek+Salata+-+A+Short+Proof+of+Nash-Williams%27+Theorem+for+the+Arboricity+of+a+Graph/15f752eb-29b1-43f4-a212-908b06f331a7.